# Python Sync Variables in multiprocessing

Tags: python, variables, synchronization, multiprocessing, shared

I'm sure this has been asked before, I looked all over and could not find anything! Don't yell at me if you find this to be a duplicate, just give a link or copy the details.

Anyways, I have this data structure, like this:

```
data = { 

    'sysstats': {
        'sysgen_time': datetime.now ( ),
        'sysgen_text': time.strftime ( "%d-%b-%y  %H:%M:%S" ),
        'connections': 0
    },

    'test': {
        'text': "ok"
    }

};
```

Now I have some code that returns what data['test']['text'] is if you type something, and if you add a parameter it will change it. You can then do the command to return it, and it will return whatever you changed it to.

I have a function to backup the data variable, so we can load again later. It is being run with multiprocessing (multiprocessing.Process), but even after the text has been updated, it will remain as it was before "ok" in the multiprocess... I want this multiprocess to sync up with the data variable.

Just use the data structure I have, and please make an example on how you would sync between one process and the rest of the file...

The reason I am using multiprocessing is because the backup code is in a while loop checking if its been 3 minutes, so it can backup... the main code already has a while loop where I would need to put the backup loop, so I just went with multiprocessing...

Please help! I tried putting it in a thread also, but it made all the text print very slowly, everything went to crap, so multiprocessing is all I can do.

Comment: Make the variable accessible to all threads and use a `threading.Lock` to do the sync_up. You may want to post your code for more help ;/

Comment: You can use a `multiprocessing.Manager` to sync across processes.  However, this really seems like a better task for `threading` ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, might I suggest the possibility of a *redesign?*

It seems, from your description, that you've launched a process/thread that's doing a *busy wait* to find out "if three minutes have gone by."

... and *then,* "unfortunately, to make matters much worse," it is going to try to proceed with its backup, *asynchronously* to the activities of the "other process" that it's supposed to be backing up!

**"Yuck!"**

Why not try *this,* instead?  Capture a *timestamp* that is "the time of the last backup."  Then, within your existing while-loop, add code which compares this timestamp to "the current time."  Has it been at-least 3 minutes yet?  If so, do the backup.  *(Yes, the main-loop will therefore be delayed until the backup is finished, **but,** you know that what gets backed-up will be stable.)*

The reason that I answer your question by (strongly) suggesting a redesign is that I think that your present strategy is going to find itself hopelessly(!) entangled in "race conditions."  (What you're seeing is "merely the *first* of them.")  Therefore, I bluntly tell ye:  **"bridge out" ahead!**  ("Don't go that way.  Turn back.")